# updating matplotlib to version 1.5 error on windows/enthought

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought, canopy

I just updated matplotlib from 1.3 to 1.5 using enthought canopy. Now when I try to import it using "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", it says that there is no module named matplotlib. I was just using it a few minutes ago on the old version and it worked fine. I am using python 2.7 through enthought canopy

Comment: *How* did you try to update matplotlib? On Canopy you should use the [`enpkg` package manager](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469690-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line) wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks. I did use the enthought package manager, selected the upgrade and hit install, as I usually do. Nothing unusual happened. the install button turned into a 'remove' button, so i thought i was good until it tried to use it and it is not recognizing the module.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed on your machine?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just did an old fashioned restart and now it works fine.